# Proof of reduction of non-homogeneous ODE problem to homogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, boundary-value-problem, homogeneous-equation

Consider the following boundary value problem:
$$-(p(x)u')'+q(x)u=g(x) \hspace{35pt} (1)\\
0<x<1, u(0)=u_l, u(1) = u_r\hspace{35pt}$$

where $p\in C^1[0,1], p(x) \ge p_0 >0; q\in C[0,1], q(x)\ge 0; g\in C[0,1]$

I want to show that if $u(x)$ is a solution of (1) then
$$y(x):=u(x)-u_l(1-x) -u_rx $$

is a solution to the system (2) below.

$$-(p(x)y')'+q(x)y=f(x) \hspace{35pt} (2)\\
0<x<1, y(0)=0, y(1) = 0\hspace{35pt}$$

So I proceed as follows:

$$y(0) = u(0)-u_l = 0\\
y(1) = u(1) - u_r = 0,$$

thus the boundary conditions are satisfied.

Now I substitute $y(x)$ into (1) and obtain

$$-(p(x)u')'+q(x)u=f(x)+p'(x)(u_l+u_r)+q(x)(u_l(1-x)-u(x)+u_rx)\hspace{35pt} (3)$$

Now how does one show that the RHS of (3) is $g(x)$? I'm quite puzzled. I'm likely supposed to somehow use the properties given for $q$ and $p$, but I don't see how these can be used. Would appreciate some hint(s).

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: What is $f(x)$ in $(2)$?

Comment: @user539887 It is just some arbitrary function.

Comment: I'm not well versed in the subtleties of the English language, so can you explain to me what you mean by "arbitrary"?  I understand your question in the following way: *for a solution $u(x)$ of $(1)$ there is a function $f(x)$ such that $(2)$ is satisfied.* And $(3)$ just gives the formula for that function.

Comment: @user539887 $f(x)$ is undefined, like $g(x)$ is. There is no formula for $f$. The only information that is given is in the problem statement.

Comment: So, I understand the problem in the following way: *For any solution $u(x)$ of $(1)$ show that there exists $f(x)$ such that $y(x)$, defined as in the second display, satisfies $(2)$*.  And you have shown that.

Comment: @user539887 No that is not what is being asked to show. What is being asked to show that if $u$ is a solution to (1) then $y$ is a solution to $(2)$. Nothing is said about $f$.